# How to initialize NumPy structured array with different default value for each column?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, matrix

I'm trying to initialize a NumPy **structured** matrix of size (x,y) where the value of x is `~ 10^3` and y's value is `~ 10^6`.

The first column of the matrix is an ID (integer), and the rest are triplets (int8), where each member of the triplet should have a different default value.

i.e. assuming the default values are `[2,5,9]` I'd like to initialize the following matrix:

```
0 2 5 9 2 5 9 2 5 9 ...
0 2 5 9 2 5 9 2 5 9 ...
0 2 5 9 2 5 9 2 5 9 ...
0 2 5 9 2 5 9 2 5 9 ...
...
```

The problem here (VS. [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29988773/how-to-initialize-numpy-array-with-different-default-value-for-each-column/)) is that **each column has a different unique name that should be recorded**.

The fastest way I could think of initializing the matrix is:

```
default_age       = 2
default_height    = 5
default_shoe_size = 9

columns = ["id", 
           "a_age", 
           "a_height", 
           "a_shoe_size", 
           "b_age", 
           "b_height", 
           "b_shoe_size",
           #...
           ]

y = len(columns)    
x = 10**4

# generate matrix
mat = numpy.zeros(shape=x,
                  dtype={"names"   : columns,
                         "formats" : ['i'] + ['int8'] * (len(columns) - 1)})
# fill the triplets with default values
for i in xrange(y/3):
    j = i * 3
    mat[mat.dtype.names[j+1]] = default_age
    mat[mat.dtype.names[j+2]] = default_height
    mat[mat.dtype.names[j+3]] = default_shoe_size
```

What is the fastest way to initialize such a matrix?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you'd rather not just use [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org) dataframes?

Comment: Something is fishy here.  You are creating a 2-d array (with shape `(x, len(columns))`), and each element of this array is itself a structure with `len(columns)` fields.  Are you sure that is what you intended?  (My guess is that you really want a *one-dimensional* structured array.)

Comment: While I haven't digested your structure description, my experience is that copying data to a structured array, field by field, is generally the fastest way to go.  Either that or make a list of all the necessary tuples.

Comment: @Warren Weckesser You're right- I did mean to create a 1D structured array, edited the question to reflect that. Thanks!

Comment: @hpaulj The matrix has to be structured. It is also huge, and would consist mainly of default values, so I'd like to fill it with those as fast as possible.

Comment: Before worrying about 'fastest', you should give us a working example.  You don't specify `x` or `y`, and your `mat[:,i+1]` indexing will not work with a structured array.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks, I corrected the code so it now works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my tweak of your sample, adjusted so it runs.  Note that I iterate over the columns by field name

```
dt=np.dtype({"names": columns, "formats" : ['i'] + ['int8'] * (len(columns) - 1)})
mat=np.zeros((10,),dtype=dt)
for i in range(1,7,3):
    mat[dt.names[i]]=default_age
    mat[dt.names[i+1]]=default_height
    mat[dt.names[i+2]]=default_shoe_size
```

producing

```
array([(0, 2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9), (0, 2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9), (0, 2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9),
       (0, 2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9), (0, 2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9), (0, 2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9),
       (0, 2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9), (0, 2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9), (0, 2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9),
       (0, 2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9)], 
      dtype=[('id', '<i4'), ('collections.ChainMap(np.arange(6).reshape(3,2))[0]_age', 'i1'), ('a_height', 'i1'), ('a_shoe_size', 'i1'), ('b_age', 'i1'), ('b_height', 'i1'), ('b_shoe_size', 'i1')])
```

As long as the number of field names is substantially few than the number of rows, I think this will be as fast, or faster, than any other way.

In my sample `x=(10,)`.  Your `mat[:,j+1]` expression has not been corrected to handle a structured 1d array.

A structured array is probably not the best way to go if you have very many columns (fields) (compared to the number of rows).

If all of your fields are 'int', I'd use a regular 2d array.  Structured arrays are most useful when fields have differing types of elements.

---

Here's a way of initializing a regular 2d array with these values, and optionally casting it to a structured array

```
values=np.array([2,5,9])
x, y = 10, 2
mat1=np.repeat(np.repeat(values[None,:],y,0).reshape(1,3*y),x,0)
```

producing:

```
array([[2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9],
       [2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9],
       ...,
       [2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9]])
```

Add on the id column

```
mat1=np.concatenate([np.zeros((x,1),int),mat1],1)
array([[0, 2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9],
       [0, 2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9],
       ...
       [0, 2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9],
       [0, 2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9]])
```

A new dtype - with all plain 'int':

```
dt1=np.dtype({"names"   : columns, "formats" : ['i'] + ['int'] * (len(columns) - 1)})
mat2=np.empty((x,),dtype=dt1)
```

If done right, the `data` for `mat1` should be the same size and byte order as for `mat2`.  In which case I can 'copy' it (actually just change pointers).

```
mat2.data=mat1.data
```

`mat2` looks just like the earlier `mat`, except the `dtype` is a little different (with `i4` instead of `i1` fields)

```
array([(0, 2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9), (0, 2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9), (0, 2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9),
       (0, 2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9), (0, 2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9), (0, 2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9),
       (0, 2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9), (0, 2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9), (0, 2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9),
       (0, 2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9)], 
      dtype=[('id', '<i4'), ('a_age', '<i4'), ('a_height', '<i4'), ('a_shoe_size', '<i4'), ('b_age', '<i4'), ('b_height', '<i4'), ('b_shoe_size', '<i4')])
```

Another way to use `mat1` values to initialize a structured array is with an intermediary list of tuples:

```
np.array([tuple(row) for row in mat1],dtype=dt)
array([(0, 2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9), (0, 2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9), (0, 2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9),
       (0, 2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9), (0, 2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9), (0, 2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9),
       (0, 2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9), (0, 2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9), (0, 2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9),
       (0, 2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9)], 
      dtype=[('id', '<i4'), ('a_age', 'i1'), ('a_height', 'i1'), ('a_shoe_size', 'i1'), ('b_age', 'i1'), ('b_height', 'i1'), ('b_shoe_size', 'i1')])
```

I haven't run time tests, in part because I don't have an idea of what your `x`,`y` values are like.

[Convert structured array with various numeric data types to regular array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26175570/convert-structured-array-with-various-numeric-data-types-to-regular-array/26183332#26183332)

or from the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/21818731/901925, the `np.ndarray` constructor can be used to create a new array using preexisting data buffer.  It still needs to use `dt1`, the all `i8` dtype.

```
np.ndarray((x,), dt1, mat1)
```

Also [ndarray to structured_array and float to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20746950/ndarray-to-structured-array-and-float-to-int), with more on using `view` v. `astype` for this conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You can build up an array using the usual `tile` and `column_stack` provided by numpy, then use [`np.core.records.fromarrays`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.core.records.fromarrays.html):

```
import numpy as np

default_age       = 2
default_height    = 5
default_shoe_size = 9
n_rows = 10

columns = [
    "id", 
    "a_age", 
    "a_height", 
    "a_shoe_size", 
    "b_age", 
    "b_height", 
    "b_shoe_size",
    ]

# generate matrix
dtype = {
    "names": columns,
    "formats": ['i'] + ['int8'] * (len(columns) - 1)
    }

ids = np.zeros(n_rows)
people = np.tile([default_age, default_height, default_shoe_size], (n_rows,2))
data = np.column_stack((ids, people))

mat = np.core.records.fromarrays(list(data.T), dtype=dtype)
```

Which gives:

```
>>> mat
rec.array([(0, 2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9), (0, 2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9), (0, 2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9),
       (0, 2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9), (0, 2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9), (0, 2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9),
       (0, 2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9), (0, 2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9), (0, 2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9),
       (0, 2, 5, 9, 2, 5, 9)], 
      dtype=[('id', '<i4'), ('a_age', 'i1'), ('a_height', 'i1'), ('a_shoe_size', 'i1'), ('b_age', 'i1'), ('b_height', 'i1'), ('b_shoe_size', 'i1')])
```

Answer (score -1):

You can fill in default values, with a for-loop. If you have the default values for example in a dictionary:

```
default_values = {
    "a_age": 3,
    "a_height": 5,
}
for column, value in default_values.items():
    mat[column] = value
```

Comment: How is this different (performance-wise) from the solution I suggested?

Comment: Where is your solution?

Comment: It's in the question itself.

Answer (score -1):

You could use an enum to represent the column names

```
class Columns(Enum):
    id = 0
    a_age = 1
    a_height = 2
    a_shoe_size = 3
    b_age = 4
    b_height = 5
    b_shoe_size = 6
    ...
```

Then use the normal array of arrays initialization and access syntax, or whatever object you want to use.  Just in place of the column index, you would use `Columns.a_age` for example.  For more information on enums, check here [How can I represent an 'Enum' in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36932/how-can-i-represent-an-enum-in-python)